# Adding multiple nouns of an inbound SMS to a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I have a working AmpScript that adds the inbound message of a text response to a Data Extension:

```
%%[ 
SET @MobileSendLogDE    = "MobileSendLog" 
SET @MOBILE_NUMBER_FIELD_LABEL   = "MobileNumber" 
SET @KEYWORD_FIELD_LABEL      = "Keyword" 
SET @UserInput_FIELD_LABEL = "UserInput"
SET @initialKeyword         = "SENDLOG" 
SET @UserInput      = Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)]) 
SET @mobileNumber      = Mobile_Number 

INSERTDATA(@MobileSendLogDE,@MOBILE_NUMBER_FIELD_LABEL,@mobileNumber,@KEYWORD_FIELD_LABEL,@initialKeyword,@UserInput_FIELD_LABEL,@UserInput)
]%%  Ok, all set. Your input is now in a data extension.
```

As soon as the text response has two words separate by a space I only get the first word into the Data Extension. I couldn't find any documentation on how to process multiple nouns. I tried with (0:1) or (0,1) but non of the them seem to work. 
The goal is to have a full text response, e.g. word1 word2 in one column in the Data Extension.

Answer (score 1):

How about `MSG(0).NOUNS`?

Source: [AMPScript Variables For Use with Mobile Messages](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/)

Comment: That did the trick. Works perfectly fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Sweet.  Please mark your question as answered.